# The database row is empty error in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

i create my own component in joomla using MVC...
i create one master table operations in client side... (add, update, delete)
but when i select one record and press delete button then following error occurred,

> Code:
>
> The database row is empty.
>   The database row is empty.

Call stack

```
#      Function      Location   
1      JSite->dispatch()      C:\wamp\www\gstest\index.php:42   
2      JComponentHelper::renderComponent()      C:\wamp\www\gstest\includes\application.php:198   
3      JComponentHelper::executeComponent()      C:\wamp\www\gstest\libraries\joomla\application\component\helper.php:357   
4      require_once()      C:\wamp\www\gstest\libraries\joomla\application\component\helper.php:388   
5      JController->execute()      C:\wamp\www\gstest\components\com_gsmasters\gsmasters.php:16   
6      gsmastersController->display()      C:\wamp\www\gstest\libraries\joomla\application\component\controller.php:754   
7      JController->display()      C:\wamp\www\gstest\components\com_gsmasters\controller.php:25   
8      gsmastersViewgsmasters->display()      C:\wamp\www\gstest\libraries\joomla\application\component\controller.php:715   
9      JError::raiseError()      C:\wamp\www\gstest\components\com_gsmasters\views\gsmasters\view.html.php:27   
10      JError::raise()      C:\wamp\www\gstest\libraries\joomla\error\error.php:251
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_gsmasters&layout=edit&id='.(int) $this->item->id); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="gsmasters-form" class="form-validate"> 
   <div class="width-60 fltlft"> 
      <fieldset class="adminform"> 
         <legend><?php echo JText::_( 'COM_GSMASTERS_GSMASTERS_DETAILS' ); ?></legend>    
         <ul class="adminformlist"> <?php foreach($this->form->getFieldset('details') as $field): ?> 
           <li><?php echo $field->label;echo $field->input;?></li> <?php endforeach; ?> 
         </ul> 
    </div>
```

please give any solution..,,
thanks.

Comment: Post some code not just a stack

Comment: you are missing the </form> tag for starters